# jquery 1.9.1 fails to parse JSON that contains escaped backslash

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

Question: how can I use the asp.net JavascriptSerializer on the server to create JSON strings that will always work with the jquery 1.9.1 parseJSON() method in IE 9?

On the server I am calling JavascriptSerializer.Serialize() on an object to convert it to a JSON string.  The object has properties which can contain a backslash. So the JavascriptSerializer takes a value like this:

```
Has\Backslash
```

And escapes it like this:

```
Has\\Backslash
```

When I run the resulting JSON string through JsonLint it is validated:

```
{"HasBackslash":"Has\\Backslash"}
```

And when I run this through JsonLint it throws a parse error:

```
{"HasBackslash":"Has\Backslash"}
```

In IE9/jquery 1.9.1 the exact opposite is acceptable.  The bit of Javascript created by JavascriptSerializer on the server fails in the browser with the error "Invalid Character":

```
var HasBackslash = $.parseJSON('{"HasBackslash":"Has\\Backslash"}');
```

But this bit of Javascript works just fine:

```
var HasBackslash = $.parseJSON('{"HasBackslash":"Has\Backslash"}');
```

Here is full example, I'm using jquery 1.9.1 and IE 9.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>The Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            var NoBackslash = $.parseJSON('{"NoBackslash":"No Backslash"}');
            $('#NoBackslash').text('NoBackslash parsed successfully');
        }
        catch(err){
            $('#NoBackslash').text('Error parsing NoBackslash: ' + err.message);
        }

        try {
            var HasBackslash = $.parseJSON('{"HasBackslash":"Has\Backslash"}');
            $('#HasBackslash').text('HasBackslash parsed successfully');
        }
        catch (err) {
            $('#HasBackslash').text('Error parsing HasBackslash: ' + err.message);
        }


        try {
            var HasEscapedBackslash = $.parseJSON('{"HasEscapedBackslash":"Has\\Backslash"}');
            $('#HasEscapedBackslash').text('HasEscapedBackslash parsed successfully');
        }
        catch(err){
            $('#HasEscapedBackslash').text('Error parsing HasEscapedBackslash: ' + err.message);
        }

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id='NoBackslash'></p>
    <p id='HasBackslash'></p>
    <p id='HasEscapedBackslash'></p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are drawing the wrong conclusions. You are changing the environment where the data is evaluated and that's why you get seemingly contradicting results.

Lets start with.

```
{"HasBackslash":"Has\Backslash"}
```

It's invalid JSON because `\B` is an invalid escape sequence.

```
{"HasBackslash":"Has\\Backslash"}
```

is valid because `\\` is a valid escape sequence. When the JSON is parsed, it will create the character `\`.

Now to:

```
$.parseJSON('{"HasBackslash":"Has\\Backslash"}');
```

Since you are working with a JavaScript string where `\` is the escape character as well, the `\` are considered to be part of the string literal. Just try

```
> console.log('{"HasBackslash":"Has\\Backslash"}');
{"HasBackslash":"Has\Backslash"}
```

You see, the *string value*, which is the real value that is passed to `$.parseJSON`, is the same as first one, which was invalid.

However,

```
$.parseJSON('{"HasBackslash":"Has\Backslash"}');
```

works, since again, you are working with a JavaScript string, so the value being parsed is

```
> console.log('{"HasBackslash":"Has\Backslash"}');
{"HasBackslash":"HasBackslash"}
```

which does not contain a backslash.

---

So, as long as you are not embedding the generated JSON into a JavaScript string, you should be fine.

Comment: I tried to explain this in my answer: It doesn't. `{"HasBackslash":"Has\\Backslash"}` is valid JSON. But when you literally use this as value of a **string**, the ``\\`` are treated as escape characters of the *string*, not the JSON value and you end up parsing invalid JSON, as shown in my answer.

Comment: When you say "as long as you are not embedding the generated JSON into a JavaScript string," what does that mean? How would you avoid doing that?

Comment: That means you should not inject JSON into JS code as string. E.g. don't do `var foo = '<% print JSON %>';` where `<% ... %>` is part of the server side template language. JSON is usually returned as response from a server or directly embedded into JS code as the value of an assignment, e.g. `var foo = <% print JSON %>;`. Then, when the JS is executed, the JSON will actually be evaluated as object literal. *"How would you avoid doing that?"* Just don't do it. It's not something that happens by accident, if it happens, you are doing it *explicitly*.

Comment: Oh for God's sake, now I understand you, thank you very much.  I'm going to add another answer just to explicate what I was doing wrong server-side.

Comment: Hi, i've got similar problem, and with no end because first parse string to json, and begin to use in winbdow as string, so began to show by <pre>json | json</pre> so give to backslash

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your patience @Felix Kling.  In sum, here is what I was doing wrong.  Server-side I was first creating a JSON string from an object:

```
string jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(myObject);
```

then, from the server, injecting this bit of javascript into the page:

```
"var o = $.parseJSON('" + jsonString + "');";
```

The problem is the call to $.parseJSON.  This is not needed; I already have a ready-made JSON object.  All I need to inject is this:

```
"var o = " + jsonString + ";";
```

And, if you are doing this in an MVC cshtml page in a block of Javascript, remember to preface with Html.Raw():

```
var o = @Html.Raw(jsonStringVariable);
```