# Why does this JSON string fail to parse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Maybe I just don't see it at the moment, but why does this JSON string fail to parse? It should be valid.

```
var content = $.parseJSON('{"foobar" : "hallo\"tow"}');
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/w6yjpame/2/

Comment: Related: [jquery 1.9.1 fails to parse JSON that contains escaped backslash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25669978/218196)

Comment: If you want to see the actual value that gets passed to `$.parseJSON`, just put `'{"foobar" : "hallo\"tow"}'` in the console and have a look at the output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're creating that JSON in a string literal, you need to escape the `\` itself:

```
var content = $.parseJSON('{"foobar" : "hallo\\"tow"}');

console.log(content);
```

---

Explanation:

In JSON, `"` characters are escaped using `\` characters.  That makes the following perfectly valid JSON:

```
{"foobar" : "hallo\"tow"}
```

Now, in your example, you were constructing this JSON value within a JavaScript string:

```
'{"foobar" : "hallo\"tow"}'
```

This introduces a subtle issue, due to the fact that JavaScript strings *also* escape `"` characters with `\` characters.  That is, the following string literal:

```
'\"'
```

... holds the value:

```
"
```

Now, applying that to your example again, we find that this string literal:

```
'{"foobar" : "hallo\"tow"}'
```

... actually holds the value:

```
{"foobar" : "hallo"tow"}
```

As you can see, we've lost our `\`.  Fortunately, this is easy to work around, as `\` characters can also be escaped with `\` characters in JavaScript strings, which is what my solution does.  So now, the revised string literal:

```
'{"foobar" : "hallo\\"tow"}'
```

gets parsed as a string holding the intended value:

```
{"foobar" : "hallo\"tow"}
```

... which can then be parsed as properly formatted JSON.

The reason you don't have this issue when reading from a `textarea` or as the result of an ajax request is that the JSON value isn't being defined by a string literal.  The extra `\` is only required due to string literal syntax, and the competition going on for who's going to escape the `"` quote first (well, not really a competition... the string literal always wins).

Comment: Damn you nailed it! Thanks a ton jmar :)

Comment: I was a bit confused. If i parse a json string i fetch with ajax or from a textarea it actually always works but thats the point with the string literal right?

Comment: Edit: moving this comment up above... running into StackOverflow comment parsing issues now :)

Comment: Ok, added an explanation to my answer.